# Should CSS link declaration be defined in full in order to maintain cross browser consistency

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Back in the old days we usually define CSS links in full markup, e.g.

```
a, a:link, a:visited, a:active {...}
a:hover {...}
```

They are needed in order to maintain cross browser consistency.

Now, I see a new trend that `:link, :visited, :active` is often ignored e.g. in Bootstrap

```
a {..}
a:hover {..}
```

Is this way to define CSS common now and able to maintain cross browser consistency?

Answer (score 0):

They mean different things. If you want to style visited vs. unvisited links, then use `a:visited` and `a:link`. If you want to style links as they're click on, use `a:active`. If hover is all you need just stick to `a:hover` like Bootstrap does.

Answer (score 0):

```
a:link
a:visited
a:active
a:hover
a:focus
```

are supported by CSS2 specifications.  So in matters of consistency, any browsers out there that have an engine supporting CSS2 or better would be able to handle these individual declarations.

There are inconsistencies in the browser's support due to the resistance of adopting the latest CSS specifications.

I would advise that you stick to CSS1 and CSS2 if you're looking for the maximum cross-browser functionality.  Only the early adopters of the new CSS specs will be up to par to the current latest of CSS4.  Mixed all across the board support for CSS3.

Comment: Good grief. What a mess. Why are you putting all those links in a comment? And for that matter, why are you linking to a whole bunch of specs that aren't even relevant?

Comment: yikes! "stick to CSS1 and CSS2"?? Just what browsers are you thinking of in your definition of "cross-browser"? I suspect it's a lot broader than mine.

Comment: @BoltClock I'm new to stackoverflow :) I shall improve my response postings.

Comment: @Spudley Yeah, we have users on IE6 and IE7 :O oh no say it ain't so!... I agree with you that most of these days when we think cross-browser we kinda take for granted that CSS3 at the minimum should be supported.  Believe you me I WISH I could use the media class :)